# How to insert OrganizationID into URL for Custom HTML Email template?

Tags: email-template, salesforce-classic, organization

I am trying to insert the organizationID into the img src url. Image is stored in Documents(Classic) on a lower level org.

```
<img border="0" beditid="r1sp1" blabel="headerImage" id="r1sp1" src="/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oid={!Organization.Id}">
```

This does not seem to work. However if I pass in the organization ID directly(X-digit code), the image is able to show up.

Tried:

Creating an object with formula field and passing in the merge field that way

Create a regular text field with the default value set to $Organization.Id

Thanks for your help in advance.